# EFAULT when using ctypes with python and calling libc accept

Tags: python, sockets, ctypes, cpython

The normal python socket module does not support protocols besides AF_INET when creating sockets:

*From cpython socketmodule.c*:

- Only AF_INET, AF_INET6 and AF_UNIX address families are supported in a
  portable manner, though AF_PACKET, AF_NETLINK and AF_TIPC are supported
  under Linux.

So I have gone about manually calling the normal BSD socket library's socket, bind, listen, and accept calls directly from libc using ctypes.
I can create the socket, bind the socket to an address, and put the socket in listen mode which require casting references to the Structure inherited SockAddr_In class that I have made:

```
CharArr14 = c_char * 14                                                                                                       
In_Addr = c_uint32                                                                                                            
CharArr8 = c_char * 8                                                                                                         


class SockAddr(Structure):                                                                                                    
    _fields_ = [                                                                                                              
        ('sa_len', c_uint8),                                                                                                  
        ('sa_family', c_uint8),                                                                                               
        ('sa_data', CharArr14)                                                                                                
    ]                                                                                                                         


class SockAddr_In(Structure):                                                                                                 
    _fields_ = [                                                                                                              
        ('sa_len', c_uint8),                                                                                                  
        ('sa_family', c_uint8),                                                                                               
        ('sin_port', c_uint16),                                                                                               
        ('sin_addr', In_Addr),                                                                                                
        ('sin_zero', CharArr8)                                                                                                
    ]
```

But when I attempt to call accept, which has an address passed that the kernel will write the connecting socket's SockAddr_In structure information, I am receiving EFAULT (errno 14) which corresponds to bad memory address.

```
def accept_sdp_sock(self):                                                                                                
    accept = libc.accept                                                                                                  
    logger.debug("Accepting socket on: {}".format(self.ip_addr))                                                          
    # int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);                                                  
    # Why is this a bad address? Is it being deallocated?                                                                 
    # Maybe it isn't allocating until we fill it with data?                                                               

    addr = SockAddr_In()                                                                                                  
    logger.debug("Memory address of addr struct: {}".format(addr))                                                        
    afd = accept(self.fd,                                                                                                 
                 cast(byref(addr), POINTER(SockAddr)),                                                                    
                 sizeof(SockAddr_In))                                                                                     
    # Check accept fd for errors                                                                                          
    if afd == -1:                                                                                                         
        self.errno = get_errno()                                                                                          
        logger.debug("Accept call failed: {} ".format(self.errno))                                                        

    return afd
```

So that we are seeing this output with the memory addresses outlined by the program

```
#truss -fead -s65535 -o truss_out python sdp_sock_cmd.py -l --address 192.168.66.140 --debug
2018-02-28 13:59:40,008 - DEBUG - This is a debug message
2018-02-28 13:59:40,009 - INFO - And an info
2018-02-28 13:59:40,009 - DEBUG - Creating SDP socket 
2018-02-28 13:59:40,010 - DEBUG - Binding SDP socket to : 192.168.66.140
2018-02-28 13:59:40,011 - DEBUG - Memory address of addr struct: <ib_socks.SockAddr_In object at 0x80385d9e0>
2018-02-28 13:59:40,012 - DEBUG - Socket listening on: 192.168.66.140
2018-02-28 13:59:40,013 - DEBUG - Accepting socket on: 192.168.66.140
2018-02-28 13:59:40,014 - DEBUG - Memory address of addr struct: <ib_socks.SockAddr_In object at 0x80385d9e0>
2018-02-28 13:59:40,015 - DEBUG - Accept call failed: 14
```

In the truss output we see this:

```
18105: 0.288079361 accept(3,0x80385da30,0x10)    ERR#14 'Bad address'
```

I've tried allocating using malloc from libc making a string buffer using create_string_buffer() from ctypes but I am seeing the EFAULT in both of those cases. Why am I seeing a EFAULT in this case? How can I allocate a data structure with python using ctypes to allow the kernel to move data to userspace?

Comment: You should define `accept`'s `argtypes` and `restype`.

Answer (score 0):

I see one obvious problem. I've used `ctypes` successfully but cannot claim to be an expert so it's possible there is some other problem as well.

I think you must be defining the argument prototype for `libc.accept` some place, but that's not in your posted source code so I will assume it's correct. Assuming the prototype is consistent with the libc binding: `accept's` third argument (`addrlen`) is a *pointer* to `socklen_t`, but you're just passing a length (*not a pointer to a length*).

The usual way this is done is that you create a `socklen_t` variable and fill it in with the size of your `addr` buffer, then `accept` (as it's completing) copies the peer's address into your `addr` buffer, truncating if it's too large, but *updating* the passed `addrlen` with the actual size. From (linux version of) `accept(2)`:

> The  `addrlen` argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by `addr`; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.
>
> The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, `addrlen` will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.

So, in summary, it is likely the *third* argument which is causing your `EFAULT` - not the second. This is supported by your `truss` output which shows `addrlen` being passed to the kernel as `0x10`: that is usually not a valid memory address.